# Is it possible to validate new line at EOF with pylint?

Tags: python, pylint

I wrote a function that search through files and

> exit(1)

if some file don't have new line at EOF.

The code working but this function is part of some pylint check that i'm doing.

I searched a lot and didn't find a thing but i'm still trying.

Pylint got some configuration that checks if file is end with new line?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is the [`missing-final-newline`](https://pylint.pycqa.org/en/latest/technical_reference/features.html#format-checker-messages) check for this (C0304):

> *Final newline missing* Used when the last line in a file is missing a newline.

You can enable it in your `pylintrc` file.

Comment: Thank you very much.
There is a way that i can make it mandatory?

Comment: What do you mean "mandatory"?

Comment: I mean that if this message is detected it will return non-zero exit code.
I tried to use "fail-on=missing-final-newline" and nothing happend

Comment: What do you mean "nothing happened"?

Comment: It only shows me the C0304 message but don't exits with non-zero, i want that if some file don't have final-newline it will exit and not only get score down

Comment: `echo -n -e '"docstring"\nprint("hello world")' > test.py && pylint test.py; echo $?` exits with code 16 for me. Without `-n` (so adding the final newline) it exits with code 0. Please open a new question _with a minimal example_ if you need more help configuring pylint for a particular behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

I will add a minimal example to explain.
My code:

```
def get_all_py_paths() -> List:
"""
Iterate over all directories and get the full path of .py files.
:return: list of absolute .py paths
"""
logging.info('Run get all path function')
file_paths = []
for root, _, files in os.walk('../'):
    for filename in files:
        if filename.endswith('.py') and '__init__' not in filename:
            filepath = os.path.join(root, filename)
            file_paths.append(filepath)
return file_paths


if __name__ == '__main__':

 files_path = get_all_py_paths()
 results = lint.Run(PYLINT_PARAMS + files_path, do_exit=False)
 print(results.option_groups)
 pylint_score = results.linter.stats['global_note']

 if pylint_score < THRESHOLD:
    exit(1)
```

and what i get is:

```
2021-10-07 14:59:23,859 - INFO - Run get all path function
************* Module update_repo 
C0304: Final newline missing (missing-final-newline)
************* Module check_rate
check_rate.py:39:15: W1514: Using open without explicitly specifying an 
encoding (unspecified-encoding)

------------------------------------------------------------------
Your code has been rated at 9.58/10 (previous run: 9.58/10, +0.00)
```

I add to my pylint config file the next lines:

```
enable=c-extension-no-member, missing-final-newline
fail-on=missing-final-newline
```

and the answer is still the same.
I want that in case that pylint detect missing-final-newline error he will immediately non-zero exit code.